# macOS Ventura 13.4 | Extend displays instead of Duplication

Tags: display, displayport, ventura, daisy-chaining

I have Apple M1 Pro 14 Inch with two monitors

Lenovo 27 Inch Monitor with USBC support and a Display Out port

LG 24 Inch - 24gm79g

I connected my laptop to Lenovo monitor via USBC and connected my LG 24-inch with DP cable using the Display Out port on Lenovo Monitor.

When I do this, Mac only detects the Lenovo Monitor and the display is duplicated between the monitors. How can I extend the displays instead?

Comment: You'll need to check the specs of the Lenovo display, to see what the Display Out port is capable of. Normally, only Thunderbolt connections have 'pass-through' capabilities.

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue :( @benwiggy, your comment makes it sound like a technology limitation of DisplayPort instead of a laziness of Apple (or $$$ mindset). From https://www.benq.com/en-us/campaign/monitor-for-mac/articles/one-cable-to-daisy-chain-all-the-monitors.html for example (a Monitor manufacturer) they say "Please note that MacBook® computer only supports daisy chaining via Thunderbolt. Daisy chaining is not supported via HDMI or using regular USB ports on any device." This is clearly an Apple limitation.